# Provisioned iPhone not showing in Xcode Organizer (or iTunes)

Tags: iphone, ios, synchronization, ios-provisioning, xcode-organizer

I've recently set up an app id and provisioning profile and was able to test my app on the device successfully. I then downloaded some sample iOS XCode projects and upon deploying one of them and deleting the sample app from the phone have since been unable to sync the phone with iTunes or see it as connected in the Xcode organizer window (the device is still listed in the lefthand pane, but shows up as disconnected). All new projects created in Xcode are now greeted with the following message when I attempt to build and run on the device.

```
No provisioned iOS device is connected.
```

I'm running Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS 4.2.

Any ideas?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and [posted about it over at Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8967/why-doesnt-itunes-detect-my-iphone). Reinstalling iTunes fixed it for me.

Comment: Slick sauce! Doing so now. Will try and return with my findings.

Comment: So, that did the trick. Odd, but at least it wasn't some black magic provisioning, SDK, or iOS conflict.

Answer (score 15):

Typically when I run across this issue I will

1. Disconnect the device
2. Clean the projects
3. Delete the device from the Organizer
4. Restart Xcode
5. Reconnect the device

Then the majority of the time the device will be recognized again. I do find it strange that even iTunes can't recognize it though. Maybe try restarting the device even?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran through this and still cannot see it. Oddly, it still vibrates when plugged in and still charges. Do you then add the device back to the organizer, and if so, how so?

Comment: Devices are auto-deteced by Organizer, you can't manually add them.

Comment: Restarting device helped me.

Answer (score 0):

On `Xcode 5.1.1`

Unplug device, remove device from `Window`->`Organizer`, `Product`->`Clean`, close `Xcode`, plug in device, start `Xcode` -  `Window`->`Organizer` and add to `Member Center`

Hope this helps. The issue occurred for me when I enabled `iCloud` and there was a sync issue on `iTunes`.