# Will building & running another iOS project disassociate existing provisioning or app id's?

Tags: iphone, ios, provisioning, xcodebuild, app-id

I recently recovered from not being able to test on my device in Xcode. After much headache, it turned out that I only needed to uninstall/reinstall iTunes, but I'd certainly rather not do so frequently.
(See: [prior thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073984/provisioned-iphone-not-showing-in-xcode-organizer-or-itunes))

The troubles seemed to begin after I built and ran some sample projects which obviously did not have my App id, etc. Is this always the case? Should I live in fear of compiling other projects that I haven't previously associated with my device and/or developer profile?

I'm not exactly sure if the App id/bundle/provisioning/keychain/whatever needs to be done per test ad hoc App or if it only matters that your device is provisioned and your plist matches what Apple has when you go to upload to the iTunes store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run many samples on my device through Xcode and never had any issues. There's certainly no reason why this should happen.

It's hard to say "No, you shouldn't be worried" without knowing what the issue is, but it's not intended to break in this way, and it doesn't for most of us!

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! confidenceToProcedeAsPlanned++;